# why $string[0] = '' is not resulting $string[0] === ''?

Tags: php

```
$s = 'abc';
$s[0] = '';
if ($s[0] !== '') {
    echo 'emmm';
}
```

Why $string[0] = '' is not resulting $string[0] === ''?

seems like $string[0] === "\0", but more confusing..

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: $s is initially a string, then you implicitly try to convert it to an array by using [0], which probably has some weird, unintented consequences. Do you have error reporting active? It's probably throwing some kind of warning. Dump out the value of $s after, see what is happening to it.

Comment: @Erik No, thats wrong. See http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: Seems its to preserve the string length : See the script http://ideone.com/d8XZTn The length is still 3 whilst only seeing 2 characters

Comment: The question: "**Why** is this happening?" comes down to two possible answers: (1) It's a bug or (2) it's by design. If (2) is the case, then there should be some reasoning for it, right? "preserving string length" seems to be the best explanation so far.

Comment: What exactly would you expect to happen when you assign *nothing* to a string offset?

Comment: Intuitively I would expect that this behaves just like `unset($array[0])`. Obviously, this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$s[0]` gives access to a single character of the string. `''` is not a character, it's a string, so the assignment fails. You get the exact same behavior if you try to assign `FALSE` to `$s[0]`. It looks like PHP does its best to convert whatever value you assign into a single character. If you assign a non-empty string, it will use the first character. If you assign a number, it will use the first digit. If you assign the value `TRUE`, it will use `1`.

Comment: The assignment doesn't fail. If you assign `''` you would expect to effectively remove the character from the string and end up with `bc`. But instead `a` is replaced with `\0`. Why is this the case?

Comment: Your assumption about what assigning `''` to a character of a string does is incorrect. Strings are stored as character arrays and you cannot remove a character from the array by simply assigning an empty string to it.

Comment: Well this just describes what is happening. We already now that. But the question is **why**?

Comment: PHP converts any value you give it into a character. `\0` is the only logical choice for an empty string.

Comment: Although I am not completely satisfied, I agree :)

Answer (score 4):

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) does specify what happens:

> Writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces. Non-integer types are converted to integer. Illegal offset type emits `E_NOTICE`. Negative offset emits `E_NOTICE` in write but reads empty string. Only the first character of an assigned string is used. **Assigning empty string assigns `NULL` byte.**

(Emphasis added)

The `$str[42] = ..` notation replaces exactly one byte in the string with exactly one byte. All the special cases are noted in the manual, like the case of assigning nothing (an empty string), in which case a `NUL` byte is assigned instead.

Comment: I even cited this part of the manual but didn't read that part... shame on me! :)

Answer (score 0):

`Why $string[0] = '' is not resulting $string[0] === ''?`

Because in this case empty string is replaced with ASCII code `NULL-byte` (`\0`, `ASCII 0` or `0x00`). And when you set part of the string with empty string, it is replace with `0x00`.

If you wish to compare nullable byte, try this:

```php
if ($s[0] !== chr('0')) {
# or
if ($s[0] !== "\0") {
```

Comment: An empty string and an ASCII NULL byte are two different things. An empty string is a string of zero length which contains nothing. A string which contains a NULL byte is a string of length 1 which contains a NULL byte.

Comment: @deceze: I scattered some words arround.

Comment: Now I've also got to criticise that a `NULL` byte is not the same as `null` though. PHP's `null` is a PHP value of type `null`. A `NULL` byte is a concept independent of PHP, it's a byte with all bits set to `0`. :o)

Answer (score -1):

when you set $s[0] == '', the string has changed, it's '\0bc', and you know '\' only escaped between "", so it's "\0" not '\0', and '' means \0.

Comment: you know the 'a' was replaced with '\0', so what did you confused. the '' in php just means \0.

Comment: When I do a `var_dump($string[0]);` this will return `string '�' (length=1)`. When I do a `var_dump('');` this will return `string '' (length=0)`.

Comment: And when I do `var_dump('' == "\0");` the result is `boolean false`. So no, `''` doesn't just mean `'\0'`.

Comment: when i use var_dump($s[0]); it print string(1) "\000"; and $s[0] == "\000" is true